# WAMP Server 2.5 Database Connection Error - Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wamp, wampserver

After upgrading latest WAMP Server to 2.5 x64 bit I'm unable to connect Wordpress config file **wp-config.php**, I google it and come to know that in latest WAMP Server they are introducing **sqli** and **PDO** for connection, I'm new to sqli kindly guide me with proper syntax of connection using it, here is the connection code which I was using previously

**wp-config.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    define('DB_NAME', 'islamic');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
    define('DB_COLLATE', '');


    $table_prefix  = 'wp_';
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);
    if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
        define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Login Failed to my dashboard, it was working before upgrading

Comment: Check your PHP error log to see if there's anything there.

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Yep, it's an issue with the install of WAMP, not something to do with your code.

Comment: Maybe. Sorry, I'm a Mac user so I can't be of much more help. My gut says to backup your stuff (including the database) and reinstall from scratch. But you might get better advice on the WAMP forums. Good luck

Comment: The change to using `mysqli_` or `PDO` as a database access extension is **not WAMPServer specific** it is because the PHP `mysql_` extensions have been **deprecated** for years now will be completely removed in `PHP7` out soon.

Comment: See [this article on the WordPress Codex](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/)

Comment: This _PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll'_ is not anything to do with your issue and can be easily fixed by clicking on the Apache version number to cause the SYMLINKS to be rebuilt. Like so: `left click wampmanager -> Apache -> Version -> 2.4.9 click on 2.4.9` and let Apache restart

Comment: i tried that @RiggsFolly but it's not helpful,but by making another **config.php** file for my new tables solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with php_intl.dll and WAMPserver 3.  It has a dependency on a dll in the wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/bin.  The installation script was supposed to create a symbolic link between the apache/bin and /wamp/bin/php/php5.6.15/ext.  I don't have full control over my machine (it's on Active Directory) and I'm no good at sym links, so I just copied all the dlls in the apache.../bin to php.../ext.  That allowed php_intl.dll to load without errors.